# VPC Peering (cross account) resolve Private Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I have an issue with private route53 via VPC peering (cross-account)
I configured VPC Peering between 2 VPC (cross-account - same region). I have one Private Route53 in one account.

- I enabled VPC Peering DNS resolved at 2 VPC
- I add full route to VPC Peering.

-> I checked ping between 2 bastions via IP Private -> Ok!

-> I tried to resolve some records in Private Route53. -> Can't solve.

Please help me! Sorry about my English skill

Comment: Are your both VPCs' DNS resolutions enabled?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate the private dns zone with the VPC in the second account.

In order to do that you need to create an authorization in account A (where the private zone is hosted), then associate the VPC in Account B, then delete the authorization in Account A.

Details on this process can be found here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-private-hosted-zone/

Comment: Is it required?